# Using custom collectionView for the UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UIView` called `MenuBar`. This menu bar is a custom "Tab Bar" that has a `collectionView` inside of it with 5 cells. When a cell is tapped, I want to present a `ViewController` but I cannot call anything like the code below in my `didSelect` method because I cannot access the present function:

```
if indexPath.item == 1 {
    let dummyController = DummyController()
    present(dummyController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Does anyone have a solution? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you guys. My code is below:

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)  
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }() 

    let seperatorView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = lightGray
        return view
    }()

    let imageNames = ["home_selected", "glimpse_selected", "camera_selected", "activity_selected", "profile_selected"]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(collectionView)
        addSubview(seperatorView)

        collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

        _ = collectionView.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

        _ = seperatorView.anchor(collectionView.topAnchor, left: collectionView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: collectionView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 1)

        setupHorizontalBar()
    }

    var horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    func setupHorizontalBar() {
        let horizontalBarView = UIView()
        horizontalBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        horizontalBarView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        addSubview(horizontalBarView)

        horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint = horizontalBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)
        horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.isActive = true

        horizontalBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        horizontalBarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/5).isActive = true
        horizontalBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4).isActive = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let x = CGFloat(indexPath.item) * frame.width / 5
        horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = x

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MenuCell

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[indexPath.item])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 5, height: self.frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 0
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a delegate for your custom view and when the view controller that owns this view creates it, it can set itself as a delegate and handle the presentation itself.

E.g.

```
protocol MenuBarDelegate: class {
  func didSelectItem(index: IndexPath, menuBar: MenuBar)
}

class MenuBar {
  weak var delegate: MenuBarDelegate?
}
```

Then in your view controller that creates the menu bar do:

```
menuBar.delegate = self
```

Implement the didSelectItem method and handle it there - you are essentially making your own version of Apple's ubiquitous delegate pattern that they use on all of their views. You may wish to model the selected item as something other than indexPath but I do not know your code.

I recommend that you always de-couple model logic from view logic. E.g., the view should never have any idea of the model it is displaying and should have no idea what to do when a user interacts with it. This should always be de-coupled and forwarded on.

Comment: Can you please provide an example in the code above? I'm a bit of a newbie. Sorry to be a pain. Thank you for your answer! Really appreciate it. Top man

Comment: You just need to add the protocol to the top of your MenuBar file and then add that property to the menuBar. Then wherever you create the MenuBar itself and add it to the view hierarchy, set the delegate to that view controller and implement the required function in your protocol definition.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Objective-C but relevant

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jeff on the point that model logic should always be de-coupled from view logic. However, I recently implemented my own Tabbar, and  I made it in the following way:

1. I had a `UINavigationController` instantiated in my AppDelegate so that I could access it from everywhere.
2. Then in your custom `MenuBar` you can access this navigationcontroller by calling `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as AppDelegate).YOURNAVIGATIONCONTROLLER` and use it to present the viewcontroller you want to present.
3. If you actually want to use your `MenuBar` as a `UITabbarController` then you should always set the viewcontroller you want to present as the rootViewController of the navigationcontroller as follows:

   var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
   appDelegate?.YOURNAVIGATIONCONTROLLER?.viewControllers = [(DummyController())!]

Hope that was useful!